# Suspect Serial Downvoting, when does the system do the check?

Tags: support, voting

[image]

The image above is a screen shot of my Rep History, in the space of 3 minutes a bunch of my questions were downvoted, particular 4 in one minute, 3 in another.

While some i could accept the downvote however some like "Do you import all Story Mode characters?" and "What are the requirements to get the floor jump?" i don't believe there was any reason to downvote them, also 7 of the 8 were the my most recent questions as such would appear at the top of my questions list, the 8th one i suspect was hunted down as it's was not a recent question which would explain the time gap

i suspect serial downvoting however i am unsure if the system had yet to detect it or if the conditions just havn't been met. so i am wondering is there like a scheduled time when the system picks this up or does it do the check every time a person downvotes?

Answer (score 8):

The system checks periodically, but it's not instantaneous. If you don't see a reversal in a few days, feel free to contact a mod or the community team to have it investigated further, but I wouldn't worry about it just yet.

Comment: I'm more worried about unanswered questions being removed by Community since once on another SE a question which had been open for a long time suddenly got a downvote and was automatically deleted and i didn't even notice until i refresh the tab i had opened (at the time i was closing off hundreds of abandoned tabs in Chrome)

Comment: Community doesn't delete anything other than Spam or Offensive content. If something was deleted, it was either done by a Moderator, or a trio of 20k users.

Comment: Community will delete closed or unanswered questions, if they have a net neutral or negative value.  Closed questions take ten days.  Unanswered questions take a year, though.

Comment: @Memor-X what Frank said; it literally takes an entire year.

Comment: ok, then i probably don't have to worry then about the system deleting some of those unanswered questions for quite a while than

Answer (score 5):

From personal experience it's reversed at 3:00 UTC.

For serial Downvoting

[image]

and serial Upvoting

[image]

Both were reversed on different days at the same time.

Comment: I don't know if its just a coincidence, but I also had a serial upvoting reversed at 03:02 UTC.

Comment: It's not a coincidence. The script runs at around 3am utc